# how to create Login screen (as a UIAlertView) in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uialertview, uianimation

How to create LoginScreen in UIViewController ? 
It should appear like UIAlertView after tapping a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since iOS 5, you can add a text field or a pair of text fields to a `UIAlertView` by modifying its `alertViewStyle` property.

There are four different options for `alertViewStyle`:

```
 UIAlertViewStyleDefault = 0,          // No text fields
 UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput,      // A single text field with secure input
 UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput,       // A single text field with plaintext input
 UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput // A pair of text fields, one with plaintext and one with a password
```

To access the text fields, you call `textFieldAtIndex:` on the `UIAlertView` instance. According to the documentation, the indices begin with 0.

**Legacy answer, before iOS 5.0:**

If you are looking to present a UIAlertView with a textbox, this is not supported in iOS in any public API, although you could walk the view hierarchy and add your own textbox.

Alternatively, create a new UIViewController subclass and present it modally. Then, you can check the values when the view is dismissed.

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore! Please consider Tilo's answer (using `UIAlertView` with `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput`)

Answer (score 6):

As of iOS5, UIAlertView now supports a login screen using the Alert Style `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput`.

C.f. [UIAlertView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertView)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/11/09/iphone-coding-tutorial-inserting-a-uitextfield-in-a-uialertview/), and add username, password fields to UIAlertView.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass UIAlertView and add UITextFields to it and define a designated initializer like this:

```
 - (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message
 delegate:(id)aDelegate
 cancelButtonTitle:(NSString*)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitle:(NSString*)otherButtonTitle { }
```

inside this method initialize your textfields and add those as `subView` to your view (subclassing UIAlertView).

Hope it helps you.